# Spring AOP: around advice without calling proceed

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I have application managed by Spring v4. I'd like to user AOP to add logging without code change but.. Generally I have tow component managed by Spring one is used for creating second one, let's call them A and B. During crating A method B.initialize is being called. To log the start of initializing I have Aspect component with appropriate pointut:

```
@Around("execution(* com.aop.B.initialize())")
```

So my problem: method initialize has a few nullable properties which will be initialized in the future with another framework so when I call proceed() the result is NullPointerException, but... when I comment proceed method and pointcut method are invoked everything works fine. Result is two records in log (those which should be before and after proceed method) and well initialized component A.

Could somebody explain me what happened here? I mean, does Around advice without direct proceed invoking works in the same way ans the Before one?

Comment: Kind of having difficulty in understanding, how b.initialize work when there is no AOP involved. What happens to those nullable params? You don't get NPE? Would be easy if you can include a sample implementation depicting the problem.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it was really not so clear. Basically after deeper investigation I've found that the issue is with another thing. During calling ProceedingJoinPoint.proceed() method some proxy object's method is called. This is the problem for my third party framework, initialize should be called from original created bean. Could you please advice how to configure such behavior? My spring components don't implement any interface and should do it.